Build a cutting plane from viewport
I'm using Blender for plaster mold creating. My way to create mold consisting of several parts is to sculpt the cutting plane which produce part of the mold by using Boolean modifier to the mold box and the object itself, while tool object is the cutting plane. Now I'm thinking how I can simplify the process of creating a cutting plane.
Mold is required to split freely when the object is casted, so I use the Mesh analysis to make the cutting line.
So, can I somehow automatically create plane that is flat on its edges but it follows the shape of the object visible from the viewport perspective in the center, like on the image?
Scripting is fine: ideally, I would like to create a plugin for mold making.


